# Translation of "It's not my job, I'm not paid to do that."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

I want to translate:

*"It's not my job, I'm not paid to do that."*

From English into Latin.

(I work somewhere where I hear the phrase every day and I'm going to have a mug printed.) Automatic translators struggle even with this simple sentence.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something snappy, *nec opus nec merces mihi est*, 'neither the task nor the reward is for me' should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Chasing another animal altogether, I came across this expression from Cicero:

> Quid igitur? Non sic oportet.

Which, out of context, means:
"So what? There's no obligation thus."

I've made a change in punctuation from the original where Cicero actually said:
"What then?" followed by a second question, "Is there not an obligation in this way?" changed to "There is no obligation in this way."

**Lewis and Short** (Perseus) gives the source of the quotation in the [**entry for "*sic*"**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=sic) but the link from the entry to a web text does not function.